# Многомерные массивы (вывод)

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Если не сложно, помогите разобраться с массивами и их выводами.
    Проблема в том, что простые массивы (ассоциативные или нет) - вывожу без проблем через foreach.

```
$tasks = [
    'Делаю' => ['Личный блог','Изучаю PHP','Изучаю HTML',],
    'Планирую' => ['Освоить Laravel','Освоить YII2'],
    'Завершенные задачи' => ['Основы HTML','Основы CSS','Основы MySql']
]

<?php foreach ($tasks as $do => $value):?>
<h2><?=$do?></h2>
<?php foreach ($value as $name): ?>
<?=$name;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Но, когда хочу вывести, к примеру, такой вид:

```
$tasks = [
    'Делаю' => [
        'title' => 'Личный блог','Изучаю PHP','Изучаю HTML',
        'content' => 'Описание','Описание','Описание',
        'action' => TRUE,
    ],
    'Планирую' => [
        'title' => 'Освоить Laravel','Освоить YII2',
        'content' => 'Описание','Описание',
        'action' => TRUE,
    ],
    'Завершенные задачи' => [
        'title' => 'Основы HTML','Основы CSS','Основы MySql',
        'content' => 'Описание','Описание','Описание',
        'action' => FALSE,
    ]
]
```

Получается только так, что либо выводятся все строки: `title , content, action`, либо появляется ошибка, когда пытаюсь указать какой-либо ключ.

Если так пишу, то все строки выводятся:

```
<?php foreach ($tasks as $do => $value):?>
<h2><?=$do?></h2>
<?php foreach ($value as $name): ?>
<?=$name;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Если пытаюсь в переменной $name указать ключ, то ошибка:

> `Warning: Illegal string offset 'title' in`

```
 <?php foreach ($tasks as $do => $value):?>
 <h2><?=$do?></h2>
 <?php foreach ($value as $name): ?>
 <?=$name['title'];?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>    
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

В итоге хочу получить следующий результат:
Когда action = FALSE - задача зачеркнута и находится в списке завершенных задач.
Когда action = TRUE - задача в списке "Планирую" или "Делаю".

В данный момент, не получается вывести только title на главной странице, а не весь массив с описание, action и тайтлом.

Comment: ты не написал какой итог ты вообще хочешь получить. в чем заключается проблема как таковая

Comment: Подправил первый пост. В данный момент, не получается вывести только title на главной странице, а не весь массив с описание, action и тайтлом.

Comment: Для этого достаточно одного цикла. например тут `foreach ($tasks as $do => $value)` в качестве `$key` будут выступать `Делаю/Планирую/Завершенные задачи`, а в качестве `$value` - массивы, которые соответствуют этим ключам... то есть чтобы вывести заголовок надо обратиться к этому полю у массива `$value['title']`........второй цикл просто проходит каждое поле уже в этом самом массиве, что, в данном случае, избыточно

Comment: я бы еще обратил внимание на строки вида `'title' => 'Личный блог','Изучаю PHP','Изучаю HTML',`, ибо тут не ключ title и значение-массив,  а просто массив из трех значений, одно из них со строковым ключом `title` и два с числовым

Comment: @teran я вот, кстати, проморгал что там не строки, а ошибки)

Comment: @Артем если ты хочешь, чтоб в `title` у тебя был массив, а на выходе слепок в виде одной строки, то тебе надо будет воспользоваться http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php  для объединения значений в строку..... но... как написал teran - у тебя сейчас там ошибка, у тебя title не массив

Comment: То есть для понятности, сейчас `Делаю` это не массив с 3мя ключами и вложенными массивами, а обычный массив из 7 элементов, где 3 ассоциативных ключа и 4 индексных. Очевидно, автор хотел сделать `title => [ .... ]`

Comment: @Артем ^^^------

Comment: " Очевидно, автор хотел сделать title => [ .... ] " - Да, запутался не много ... Спасибо! Попробую сделать так.

Comment: @Артем не забудь про implode. он будет скорее всего уместнее, чем второй цикл

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого можно использовать рекурсивную [функцию](https://habrahabr.ru/post/280944/).

```
$tasks = [
  'Делаю' => [
    'title' => 'Личный блог','Изучаю PHP','Изучаю HTML',
    'content' => 'Описание','Описание','Описание',
    'action' => TRUE,
  ],
  'Планирую' => [
    'title' => 'Освоить Laravel','Освоить YII2',
    'content' => 'Описание','Описание',
    'action' => TRUE,
  ],
  'Завершенные задачи' => [
    'title' => 'Основы HTML','Основы CSS','Основы MySql',
    'content' => 'Описание','Описание','Описание',
    'action' => FALSE,
  ]
];
function each_array($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        // к примеру 
        echo $key.'---';
        if(is_array($val)){
            each_array($val);
        }
        else{
            echo $val.'<br>';
        }
    }
}

each_array($tasks);
```